# How to create a list or dataframe

Tags: scala

I'm testing a case where whatever columns are included in Join are actually present in the correct dataframe or not.

Let's say i have 2 DF's defined as a case class

```
case class JoinResult(
    id: Option[String],
    name: Option[String],
    maxAttack: Option[Int],
    maxDefense: Option[Int],
    cartoon: Option[String]
)

case class JoinSchema(
    uuid: String,
    cartoon: String
)
```

In this JoinResult schema is the `parentDF` and JoinSchema is `childDF`

To join this i'm running a spark job which will take a `dslString` Something like

```
"""
        |{
        |  "with": "D2",
        |  "type": "left",
        |  "keys": {
        |             "D1.id": "D2.uuid"
        |           },
        |  "colList": [
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D1.id",
        |                     "as": "id"
        |                  },
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D1.name",
        |                     "as": "name"
        |                  },
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D1.max_attack",
        |                     "as": "max_attack"
        |                  },
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D1.max_defense",
        |                     "as": "max_defense"
        |                  },
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D2.cartoon",
        |                     "as": "cartoon"
        |                  },
        |                  {
        |                     "col": "D2.test_cols",
        |                     "as": "test_cols"
        |                  }
        |              ]
        |}
        |""".stripMargin
```

My End requirement is to check all the cols which start with `D2` aliasing should be there in `childDF` and cols starting with `D1` aliasing should be there in `parentDF` And if none of the column is there then it should throw me an error.

To achieve this i'm writing a function to iterate over the `col` present in the `dslString` and the ones starting with `D1` should be stored into `parentInvCols` and `cols` starting with `D2` should be stored in `childInvCols`.

Here is the main function

```
config.colList.foreach { cInfo =>
      val colInfo = cInfo.col.split("\\.")
      if (childAlias.equals(colInfo.head)) {
        colInfo.last
      }
    }
```

So as per the code if `childAlias = colInfo.head` means `D2 = D2` then it should store in `childInvCols`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
val cols: Map[String, Seq[String]] = config
   .colList
   .map(_.col)
   .map(_.split("\\."))
   .groupMap(_.head)(_.last)
```

It creates a map with prefixes (`D1`, `D2` etc.) as keys and lists of corresponding column names as values